# How to create a household object model(3D mesh)?

Tags: ros, model

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using household objects database. The problem is that I don't know how to build an object(ie:can,bottle) 3D model,in http://www.ros.org/wiki/household%20objects , using orthographic method(what about the process?).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9399/how-to-create-a-household-object-model(3d-mesh)?/) by [kexiang](https://answers.ros.org/users/283/kexiang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2011-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The link you give has a brief summary of the two methods that they used to create the models.

I suspect that following the ICRA solutions in perceptions challenge there will be a number of methods published (probably with OpenSource libraries) that detail various approaches to this process.

---

Originally posted by [Nick H](https://answers.ros.org/users/152/nick-h/) with karma: 214 on 2011-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1